# generating excluded list based on a map and dynamic user selection

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a lookup object which keys are tourIds and values are available destinations for that tour.

User should be able to select individual cities. However I need to disable cities which are not available as a destination of tour based on selected cities by user.

As an example lets say we have list of 3 cities: Rome, Florence and Venice and there is a tour to visit Florence and Venice. So If user selects Florence and Venice, Rome must be disabled.

Here is my lookup

```
{
    "1": ["Paris"],
    "2": ["London"],
    "3": ["Rome"],
    "4": ["Florence"],
    "5": ["Venice"],
    "12": ["Paris", "London"],
    "13": ["Paris", "Rome"],
    "14": ["Paris", "Florence"],
    "15": ["Paris", "Venice"],
    "21": ["London", "Paris"],
    "23": ["London", "Rome"],
    "24": ["London", "Florence"],
    "25": ["London", "Venice"],
    "123": ["Paris", "London", "Rome"],
    "124": ["Paris", "London", "Florence"],
    "125": ["Paris", "London", "Venice"],
    "213": ["London", "Paris", "Rome"],
    "214": ["London", "Paris", "Florence"],
    "215": ["London", "Paris", "Venice"],
    "1234": ["Paris", "London", "Rome", "Florence"],
    "1235": ["Paris", "London", "Rome", "Venice"],
    "2134": ["London", "Paris", "Rome", "Florence"],
    "2135": ["London", "Paris", "Rome", "Venice"],
    "21345": ["London", "Paris", "Florence", "Venice"]
}
```

and assume user selected these two cities:

```
selecteddCities = ["Venice", "Florence"]
```

I need to have an array, disabledCities, which includes cities that there is no tour to that destination depending on currently selected cities. which in this case is Rome. Because there is no tour to cover Venice, Florence and Rome.

ES6 and Lodash are available to use. Whats the best wat to generate disabledCities array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand but i'm guessing you want to filter the primary list down to 2 list enabled tours, and disabled tours. And for the tour to be enabled it needs to contain all of the user selected cities. Here is some example code to filter these out based on user selected array.

```js
var tours = [
    {tourIds : "1", cities : ["Paris"]},
    {tourIds : "2", cities : ["London"]},
    {tourIds : "3", cities : ["Rome"]},
    {tourIds : "4", cities : ["Florence"]},
    {tourIds : "5", cities : ["Venice"]},
    {tourIds : "12", cities : ["Paris", "London"]},
    {tourIds : "13", cities : ["Paris", "Rome"]},
    {tourIds : "14", cities : ["Paris", "Florence"]},
    {tourIds : "15", cities : ["Paris", "Venice"]},
    {tourIds : "21", cities : ["London", "Paris"]},
    {tourIds : "23", cities : ["London", "Rome"]}
]

var userSelCities = ['Paris','London']



var areCitiesInTour = function(tour){

    var CitiesFound = 0

        for (var i = 0; i < tour.cities.length; i++) {

            for (var x = 0; x < userSelCities.length; x++) {
                if (tour.cities[i] === userSelCities[x]) {
                    CitiesFound += 1;
                }
            }
        }


    return(CitiesFound === userSelCities.length);
}

var areCitiesNotInTour = function(tour){

    var CitiesFound = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < tour.cities.length; i++) {

        for (var x = 0; x < userSelCities.length; x++) {
            if (tour.cities[i] === userSelCities[x]) {
                CitiesFound += 1;
            }
        }
    }


    return(CitiesFound !== userSelCities.length);
}

    var enableTours =  tours.filter(areCitiesInTour)
    var disabledTours = tours.filter(areCitiesNotInTour)

    console.log(enableTours)
    console.log(disabledTours)
```